# Convert array in string format from cell in pd.DataFrame to ndarray in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I got an dataframe where one column is image pixels as arrays in string format and I want to convert them to actual arrays.
Here an example where I printed one cell.

```
X[0] = `
[[[164 164 164]
  [164 164 164]
  [162 162 162]
  ...
  [ 54  54  54]
  [ 54  54  54]
  [ 54  54  54]]

 [[164 164 164]
  [164 164 164]
  [162 162 162]
  ...
  [ 54  54  54]
  [ 54  54  54]
  [ 54  54  54]]

 [[164 164 164]
  [164 164 164]
  [162 162 162]
  ...
  [ 54  54  54]
  [ 54  54  54]
  [ 54  54  54]]

 ...

 [[ 84  84  84]
  [ 84  84  84]
  [ 84  84  84]
  ...
  [ 50  50  50]
  [ 51  51  51]
  [ 51  51  51]]

 [[ 84  84  84]
  [ 84  84  84]
  [ 83  83  83]
  ...
  [ 51  51  51]
  [ 51  51  51]
  [ 51  51  51]]

 [[ 84  84  84]
  [ 84  84  84]
  [ 84  84  84]
  ...
  [ 51  51  51]
  [ 51  51  51]
  [ 51  51  51]]]
```

I tried doing it in a preprocessing step but that doesn't work

```
def preprocess(image):
  """
  Takes an image array, turns it into tensor and normalizes the values 
  """

  image = tf.cast(np.ndarry(image), tf.float32)
  # turn arrays of data into tensors
  image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, tf.float32)

  # normalize image 
  image = image/255.0

  return image 

preprocess(X[0])
```

EDIT (format the dataset to be a dataframe structure with arrays and labels):

````
def create_data(datadir):
  """
  Creates a list of images and their labels from a given directory (datadir)
  """
  for category in Classes:
    path = os.path.join(datadir, category)
    label = Classes.index(category) 
    for image in os.listdir(path):
      try:
        image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
        image = cv2.resize(image_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        data.append([image, label])
      except Exception as e:
        pass 
```
any alternative suggestions?

Thank you in advance
````

Comment: Please produce a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sure wait a sec

Comment: Is X[0] a string? What does `type(X[0])` give you?

Comment: It is recommended to provide simple sample data of the image. Do you see `...` in your data? How can one interpret the values in ...?

Comment: Sorry to both of you. I had problems with my wifi yesterday and still fixing the problem there. I will get back to you later @Roxy

Comment: @Mercury it is a string

Comment: @Roxy here a link to the dataset. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/msambare/fer2013 
I will do an edit on how i formatted it.